# Where am I going wrong in visualizing this simple vector field?

Tags: calculus, physics, vector-analysis, vector-fields, fluid-dynamics

The velocity vector field given by

$$ \vec{U}(x, y) = \langle u_x, u_y \rangle = \langle a cos(\lambda x), a sin(\lambda x) \rangle,$$

where a is the fixed amplitude, and lambda is the fixed wavelength, does not describe a circle with radius $a$; instead, plotting this vector field in matlab shows a nice, wavy profile.

Where am I mistaken?  To me, it looks like the parameterization of a circle.

Comment: Frequency is measured in # per second.   Monthly is 12/year.

Comment: @Hurkyl The vector from (3,2) to (0,0)?

Comment: How is u a vector field?  You have defined it only as one vector, some point in R^2.

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer, so a brief comment: if you gather up all of the vectors drawn and relocate them to the origin, their tips *will* trace out a circle. The wavy profile is that you are dragging the base of the arrow horizontally as the vector circles around its base. (at least, if what's going on is what I think is going on)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we look at your equation, assuming that your parameter x is in fact the polar angle $\theta$, then our vector field looks like.
$$\vec u=a (cos(n \theta), sin(n \theta))$$
The we have a field of vectors, whose strength doesn't depend on position, but the directions rotates as a multiple of the angle.

It's a little bit like the rotation and revolution of a planet.  As we look at various angles around the origin, the direction of the vector field changes.

---

These diagrams look like

$n=1$

[image]

---

$n=2$

[image]

---

$n=3$

[image]

---

$n=4$

[image]

---

If you really do mean x and not the polar angle $\theta$, then our equation is 
$$\vec u=a (cos(n x), sin(n x))$$

and you get diagrams that look like this.

[image]

And this

[image]

As we move from left to right along the x direction, the direction of the vector field rotates.  Up and down along the y direction the vector field is constant.

Comment: You're assuming that in the OP, $(a, x)$ refers to the polar coordinates of a point, and you wrote those coordinates as  $(a, \theta)$ instead? It's probably worth explicitly mentioning your assumption at the top, since it's not standard.

Comment: I had a small glitch in the code and the diagrams weren't exactly what I wanted.  The new diagrams are up, with a constant field strength.